# What is the right way to import an Android Studio project into GitHub?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github, repository

I think I followed right steps. After the enabling Github repo in VCS I tried to share Project on Github. At that moment there is an error saying failed to connect Github

VCS->Import into version control-> Share project on GitHub

After following this steps below error will appear.

[image]

Are there any missing steps?

Comment: The dialog states the problem clearly : You've entered incorrect user credentials for your github account.

Comment: I tried to add my GitHub acc.
Setting -> Version Control -> GitHub
When I entered the details that asked it also shows same error

Comment: Just for infromation, you can also share the project on github through command line also

Comment: Can you login to your GitHub account on their website? Maybe something is wrong with your account?

Comment: Yeah I can sign into my account. in the **Setting -> Version Control -> GitHub** box what should I input as HOST: ??

Comment: Found the mistake that I've done. We must type HOST as **github.com** . Thank you all for your valuable time.